# Animation is not properly renderd

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have created this Blend of a Tornado in cycles. Im done with it as far as it goes, but if i want to render the animation it is only showing the 2 particle emitting circles. There must be an issue in my render setting. I have no clue what it could be. 
I hope someone can help me.
Thank you already <3

[image]

Comment: Did you bake the particle's cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it also shows the smoke but it's hidden by your emitter. As explained [here](https://blenderartists.org/t/invisible-smoke-emitter/588741/2), "you can actually just turn off render visibility on the emitter. It’s the domain object that actually renders. " So disable the emitter's visibility.

[image]

Comment: i have found the option to hide the object in render in the object menu so thank you for that, but how do i get the camera icon and the monitor you have there for me theres only the "hide" eye.

Comment: I've edited my answer, to enable these icons, click on the key icon (filter) on the top

Comment: Thank you everything worked perfectly. Now im Just waiting for the finished Render